# Reading polynomial

Tags: c++, struct, compilation, polynomial-math

Hi I have a problem in reading the polynomial I've created. I have to implement some operations, but i have a problem with the reading phase, I didn't find any solution.
The errors are those:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Big HW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp||In instantiation of 'void Polynomial<T>::readP() [with T = int]':|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|58|required from here|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|31|error: no matching function for call to 'Queue<int>::enqueue(term&)'|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|31|note: candidate is:|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\queue.h|17|note: void Queue<T>::enqueue(T) [with T = int]|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\queue.h|17|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'term' to 'int'|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp||In instantiation of 'void Polynomial<T>::invert() [with T = int]':|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|59|required from here|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|50|error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Queue<int>' and 'int')|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|50|error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Queue<int>' and 'int')|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp||In instantiation of 'void Polynomial<T>::computeX(T) [with T = int]':|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|60|required from here|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|42|error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Queue<int>' and 'int')|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|42|error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Queue<int>' and 'int')|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|42|error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Stack<int>' and 'int')|
C:\Facultate Personal\DSA\Big HW\big_hw.cpp|42|error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Stack<int>' and 'int')|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 6 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

The read function and main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "queue.h"
#include "stack.h"
using namespace std;

struct term{
int coef;
int expo;};

template<typename T> class Polynomial{
private:
T coef;
T expo;
public:
Queue<T> polin;
int n;
struct term *p;


Polynomial(){}
~Polynomial(){}

void readP()
{
    cout<<"Please insert the maximum grade of the polynomial: "; cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Please insert the coefficient for x^"<<(n-i)<<": "; cin>>p[i].coef;
        p[i].expo=n-i;
        polin.enqueue(p[i]);

    }
    cout<<endl;
}
};
int main()
{
Polynomial<int> polin;
polin.readP();
polin.invert();
polin.computeX(2);
return 0;
}
```

The enqueue function is this:

```
void enqueue(T x) {
        if (size >= NMAX) {
            cout << "The queue is FULL" << endl;
            return;
        }

        queueArray[tail] = x;
        tail=(tail+1)%NMAX;
        size--;
    }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please post the errors as text in your question.

Comment: Done, sorry, my first post.

Comment: You're accessing a pointer with an indexing operator: ```struct term *p;``` ```p[i]```, which yields undefined behaviour (in this case at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are pretty self explanatory:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Queue<int>::enqueue(term&)
```

You're passing a term object into the enqueue function which expects an `T` (=int). maybe you meant to pass `p[i].coef` or `p[i].expo` ?

```
error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Queue<int>' and 'int')
```

It doesn't look like `Queue` has an indexing operator.

**Edit:**

I noticed something else too. When you read the `term`s, you're putting them into the `struct term *p` variable, but accessing it with `p[i]`. That means that if i > 0 you're in undefined behaviour territory.

My Suggestion would be to get rid of the `p` variable and write your for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    term t;

    std::cout << "Please insert the coefficient for x^" << (n - i) << ": ";
    std::cin >> t.coef;
    t.expo = n - i;

    polin.enqueue(t);
}
```

Comment: I have to keep every term of the polynomial in a circular queue, and a term of the polynomial has an exponent and a coefficient. I have to keep them both somehow.

Comment: Then why have a ```Queue<T>```, why not just a ```Queue<term>```?

Comment: I changed it with Queue<term>. Now I can compile it but after I read the grade and the coeficient it stops working. And also the other functions have some problems with that Queue<term>, but it will be managable